# How can I add user location (Office) to SharePoint survey results?

Tags: office, survey, geolocation

SharePoint survey results include a "Created By" field that indicates who submitted the survey. How can we pull in additional user profile details into the survey results? Specifically, we would like Office (location) in the results (autopopulated). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new column in survey list and populate the users office\location who is responding to the survey via (rest api\Jsom).

Survey list is special list, you will not find option to add column directly.
Option to add is hidden, but still supported.

Here is the step to find the link
1.  Go to normal list, 
2.  click add new column link
3.  copy the url and
4.  change the list name with your survey list

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Can you provide instructions for populating the users office\location via rest api\Jsom?

Comment: here is the blog http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html for getting userprofile information for fetching user profile information